# What is the derivative of the inverse of the unit quaternion?

Tags: rotations, quaternions

the unit quaternion is a good way to represent the rotation. but does anyone know the following formula is right or not?I am trying to prove it by myself but I am stuck on it.
$\dot{(q^{-1})}=-q^{-1}*\dot{q}*q^{-1}$ where q is a unit quaternion,* is the quaternion multiplication.

Comment: Yes,you are right.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are assuming $q(t)$ is a quaternion-valued function of a real variable $t$.

One thing you can check is that the product rule works for quaternion-valued functions. Indeed, the usual proof works, you just have to be careful not to use the commutative proprety.

Then, defining $p(t):=q(t)^{-1}$, we may differentiate $p(t)q(t)=1$ to obtain

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}t}q+p\frac{\mathrm{d}q}{\mathrm{d}t} = 0. $$

Can you finish?

Comment: Yes. the proof is as follows:$\dot{p}*q+p*\dot{q}=0$,then$\dot{p}*q=-p*\dot{q}$,then$\dot{p}=-q^{-1}*\dot{q}*q^{-1}$